# Odata V4 - entity null when trying to add one

Tags: c#, http-post, odata

User class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OdataProjectTest.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String FacebookId { get;set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? RegisterDate { get; set; }
        public int Wins { get; set; }
        public int Loses { get; set; }
        public int GameCount { get; set; }


        public ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Users controller

```
using OdataProjectTest.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;

namespace OdataProjectTest.Controllers
{
    public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        Context db = new Context();
        private bool UserExists(int key)
        {
            return db.Users.Any(p => p.Id == key);
        }
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        // get
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<User> Get()
        {
            return db.Users;
        }
        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<User> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            IQueryable<User> result = db.Users.Where(p => p.Id == key);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }
        //

        // pentru add
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(User user)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
          //  user.RegisterDate = new System.DateTimeOffset();
            db.Users.Add(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Created(user);
        }
        //

        // pentru edit
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Patch([FromODataUri] int key, Delta<User> user)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }
            var entity = await db.Users.FindAsync(key);
            if (entity == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            user.Patch(entity);
            try
            {
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!UserExists(key))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }

            }
            return Updated(entity);
        }
        //

        // delete
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Delete([FromODataUri] int key)
        {
            var user = await db.Users.FindAsync(key);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }
        //
    }
}
```

I've done some debug and when it gets here

```
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(User user)
                {
 // here the user is null, but the modelstate.isvalid is true
                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);
                    }
                  //  user.RegisterDate = new System.DateTimeOffset();
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return Created(user);
                }
```

The request:

```
POST localhost..../Users HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json;odata.metadata=full
Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=full
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0
OData-Version: 4.0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Host: localhost..blabla
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-Olingo/4.0.0-beta-01

104
{"@odata.type":"#OdataProjectTest.Models.User","FacebookId@odata.type":"String","FacebookId":"maicata","Name@odata.type":"String","Name":"sme","Wins@odata.type":"Int32","Wins":1,"Loses@odata.type":"Int32","Loses":1,"GameCount@odata.type":"Int32","GameCount":1}
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work if you add the [FromBody] attribute on the user parameter?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] User user)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I played around a little and the only way I could get a null parameter value with IsValid = true was if I POSTed an empty body - you obviously aren't doing that :). Could you try sending the request without chunked encoding and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Idk how but I fixed it. THanks anyways

Comment: Glad to hear! Let us know if you ever figure out what was going on, id be curious to know.

Comment: I was generating that request with Olingo, maybe I was doing it wrong. Now i changed my way of using Olingo, now I'm generating the classes manually, and use them, like a cool entity framework.